# Некорректный подсчет функции (язык C)

Tags: c, функции, математика, ряды

В лабе задали подсчитать такую функцию двумя циклами для заданного пользователем N.
[image: функция]

Однако при любом N, даже 1 выводиться, как я понял, позитивная бесконечность. В чем может быть ошибка и как ее исправить?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
double P=1;
double S=0;
int n;
int i;
int j;
printf("Please insert N \n");
scanf("%d", &n);
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
    {
    S=S+(4*j/3-1);
    }

P=P*((i+sqrt(i))/S);
S=0;
}
printf("%lf \n",P);

return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как минимум, вот здесь

```
(4*j/3-1)
```

у вас **целочисленное деление**, т.е., например, при `j==1` получается 0...

Пишите как `(4.0*j/3.0-1)`...

Далее, у вас S инициализируется вне всех циклов, а считается с самого начала - что тоже неверно.

Больше не смотрел.

А вообще, если бы это делал я, то ограничился бы одним циклом:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    unsigned int N = 0;
    printf("N = ");
    scanf("%u",&N);

    double P = 1.0;
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
    {
        P *= 3.0*(i+sqrt(i))/(i*(2.0*i-1));
    }
    printf("Result = %lf\n", P);
}
```

Сумму арифметической прогрессии считать через ряд - издевательство :)

**Update1**

Ну не поднимается рука на второй цикл!...

```
double monoCycle(unsigned int N)
{
    double P = 1.0;
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
    {
        P *= 3.0*(i+sqrt(i))/(i*(2.0*i-1));
    }
    return P;
}

double biCycle(unsigned int N)
{
    double P = 1.0;
    double S = 0.0;
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
    {
        P *= (i+sqrt(i))/(S += 4.0*i/3 - 1);
    }
    return P;
}



int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    unsigned int N = 0;
    printf("N = ");
    scanf("%u",&N);

    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
    {
        printf("Result(%d) = %20lg   %20lg\n", i, monoCycle(i),biCycle(i));
    }
}
```

Кстати, этот вариант оказывается едва ли не быстрее предыдущего...

**Update2**

Это выше моих сил, но...

```
double biCycle(unsigned int N)
{
    double P = 1.0;
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
    {
        double S = 0.0;
        for(unsigned int j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
            S += 4.0*j/3 - 1;
        P *= (i+sqrt(i))/S;
    }
    return P;
}
```

Но это - издевательство над здравым смыслом.

Comment: Про инициализацию S и целочисленное деление вы верно подметили, спасибо. А касательно циклов задача посчитать и одним, и двумя, и вот как раз со вторым вариантом и возникла проблема.)

Comment: Понимаете... Ну нет тут места для второго цикла. Ведь S(i) находится из S(i-1)! Так что даже если считать S, то получится как в Update1...

Comment: и тем не менее, наш препод сказал сделать это и вложенными циклами, и динамическими программированием) Делаем как говорит.

Comment: Ну, можно тогда считать с конца с мемоизацией S... :) Вон там, в Update2, два цикла... :(

Comment: По факту, ваш upd2 и есть мой первоначальный цикл, только i это ансайнед)

Comment: Естественно. А как же иначе? Задача-то одна, откуда ж взяться разным решениям? :)

Comment: Ну так да) Главное что она теперь решена)

Answer (score 2):

Вы пользуетесь целыми числами (`int`) и потому результаты деления тоже целыми числами: `12 / 15 == 0`.

Используйте десятинную точку (`12. / 15 == 0.8`) и `float` или `double` для определения переменных.